# Dynamics of space curves using frenet serret formulas

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, animation, differential-geometry

I am trying to animate the dynamics of a space curve for which the curvature and torsion are given as a function of time. Using Frenet Serret equations, I want to find out the dynamics of the curve. So, I'm trying this, but the plot is not working.

```
sol = First@
With[{κ = Sech[s - a], τ = 1}, 
ParametricNDSolve[{{t'[s], n'[s], 
   b'[s]} == {{0, κ, 0}, {-κ, 
     0, τ}, {0, -τ, 0}}.{t[s], n[s], b[s]}, 
 t[0] == Normalize[{1, 1, 1}], n[0] == Normalize[{-1, 1, 0}], 
 b[0] == Cross[t[0], n[0]], t[s] == r'[s], r[0] == {1, 0, 0}}, {t,
  n, b, r}, {s, -300, 300}, {a}]]

Manipulate[
With[{scale = 4}, {rr, tt, bb, nn} = {r[s][a], t[s], b[s], n[s]} /. 
sol;
Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[ss][a] /. sol, {ss, -30, 30}], 
Graphics3D[{{Directive[Red], 
   Arrow[{rr, scale tt + rr}]}, {Directive[Blue], 
   Arrow[{rr, scale nn + rr}]}, {Directive[Green], 
   Arrow[{rr, scale bb + rr}]}}, PlotRange -> Full] /. 
sol]], {{s, -30}, -30, 30, .01}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Among other things, you seem mixing up `r` and `t`. Moreover, the parameter `a` in `ParametricFunction` objects as to be submitted first. So it should probably be `{rr, tt, bb, nn} = {r[s], t[a][s], b[s], n[s]} /. 
sol`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

`ParametricNDSolveValue` makes things a lot easier since no replacements have to be performed:

```
sol = With[{κ = Sech[s - a], τ = 1}, 
   ParametricNDSolveValue[{{t'[s], n'[s], 
       b'[s]} == {{0, κ, 0}, {-κ, 
         0, τ}, {0, -τ, 0}}.{t[s], n[s], b[s]}, 
     t[0] == Normalize[{1, 1, 1}], n[0] == Normalize[{-1, 1, 0}], 
     b[0] == Cross[t[0], n[0]], t[s] == r'[s], r[0] == {1, 0, 0}}, {t,
      n, b, r}, {s, -300, 300}, {a}]];

Manipulate[
 With[{scale = .1}, {rr, tt, bb, nn} = sol[a];
  Show[
   ParametricPlot3D[rr[ss], {ss, -30, 30}],
   Graphics3D[{{Directive[Red], 
      Arrow[{rr[s], tt[s] + rr[s]}]}, {Directive[Blue], 
      Arrow[{rr[s], scale nn[s] + rr[s]}]},
     {Directive[Green], Arrow[{rr[s], bb[s] + rr[s]}]}
     }],
   PlotRange -> All
   ]
  ], {{s, -30}, -30, 30, .01}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thank you Henrik!

Comment: You're welcome!